# Where does Calendar store passwords?

Tags: password, calendar, keychain

My organization has users rotate our passwords.  I change my Active Directory password, then I need to go to various apps that use it and update their login information.

Most apps seem to store their credentials in the `local` keychain of Keychain Access, so I can go to the Keychain and update it there.  But for Calendar.app, all I seem to be able to do is open the app, let it fail, and then give my updated password.

If it's using the System Preferences -> Internet Accounts mechanism (not sure), then where are those things stored?  I don't see it updating any of the items I see in Keychain.

Comment: As I have no need to connect to **Active Directory**, nonetheless, have you looked in **Calendar** > **Preferences…** > **Accounts**?

Comment: @user3439894 In order to do that, you have to open Calendar, at which point it will try (and fail) to connect.  That's something I'm trying to avoid because it can lead to account lockout.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I though when you said "all I seem to be able to do is open the app, let it fail, and then give my updated password." I thought it was letting you into the _application_, at which point you'd be able to check. My bad.